# Add Commitment Type or purpose sign document in digital signature excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, openxml

I am trying to add commitment type and purpose sign document to excel file using poi library in digital signature using java code.
Or if the poi library can't provide it yet, is there a library that can do the same.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjWzI.png)

Comment: in POI, you can add your own SignatureFacet to the SignatureConfig and modify the sig1.xml. Just have a look at the existing SignatureFacets on how to do this.  I will try to provide some example code soon

Comment: I've implemented the commitment type and purpose description in my [poi-examples repo](https://github.com/kiwiwings/poi-examples/tree/main/src/main/java/de/kiwiwings/poi/dsig). Unfortunately that's a lot of code to be duplicated from the POI sources and there seems to be also a marshalling problem in POI with adding the namespaces to the correct nodes. I'll try to provide the use case in the POI standard facets, so it will be only a matter of setting the values in the SignatureConfig.

Comment: I've fixed it via [#65672](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65672). With POI 5.2.0 you will be able to set it via `SignatureConfig.setCommitmentType()` and `SignatureConfig.setSignatureDescription()`

Comment: Thanks for your enthusiasm and professionalism @kiwking, your code worked great for me. Can you tell me when poi will release version 5.2.0

Comment: 5.1.0 was just released, so I guess it will be around March-May 2022 for 5.2.0 to go live. either a) use my poi-examples version, b) apply the patch in the bugzilla entry to 5.1.0 or c) use the [nightly](https://ci-builds.apache.org/job/POI/job/POI-DSL-1.8/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/)